# iOS 8 Multitasking Snapshot / Screenshot and sensitive information

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In the [App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW8) for iOS Apple Says

*Remove sensitive information from views before moving to the background.
When an app transitions to the background, the system takes a snapshot of the app’s main window, which it then presents briefly when transitioning your app back to the foreground. Before returning from your applicationDidEnterBackground: method, you should hide or obscure passwords and other sensitive personal information that might be captured as part of the snapshot.*

However, if you try to remove sensitive data dismissing a View Controller:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    [[self.window rootViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Dismissing");
    }];

    NSLog(@"method returning");
}
```

The screenshot is taken *before* the View Controller is dismissed.
At the next application launch you will see the correct View Controller (the initial one, without the sensitive data).

This happens because `dismissViewControllerAnimated` seems to be async, so it's enqueued and really executed after `applicationDidEnterBackground` returns. 
The problem is that, as specified in the Apple docs, the screenshot is taken when `applicationDidEnterBackground` returns, not after.

I'm sure that this wasn't happening in the previous versions of iOS (maybe before iOS 7).
The `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` method was completed before `applicationDidEnterBackground` returned.

I know that:
- I can move this logic into `applicationWillResignActive` (but this will trigger even when a reminder fires, or the user opens the control center)
- I can create a view that covers my sensitive data and add it to the main window

But I don't want this. I simply want it to work like before. I want that `dismissViewControllerAnimated` is executed and *completed* before the `applicationDidEnterBackground` returns.

I filed a bug about that (but reading around I'm not the only one, during these last years)

Any trick to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I answer to my own question in a Q&A style because I found a solution myself.

The first thing I tried was to use semaphores to stop the execution of the code after the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` method

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sema =  dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [[self.window rootViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Dismissing");
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

This obviously doesn't work, because the semaphore stops the main thread, which is needed to complete the dismissal of the view controller (the dismissal is enqueued on the main thread).

So I remembered about runLoops. One of the things that a runLoop does is to executed the task queued by GCD on the queue of its associated thread.
So I ended up with this code:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    [[self.window rootViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Dismissing");
    }];


    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components: NSCalendarUnitEra | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate: [NSDate date]];
    [comps setSecond:comps.second+2];
    NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSLog(@"Before Runloop");
// make the runLoop run for the next two seconds
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:endDate];
    NSLog(@"After Runloop");

    NSLog(@"method returning");
}
```

This method produces this output:

> 2015-01-27 09:30:21.923 TestBackground[60867:1741136] Before Runloop
>   2015-01-27 09:30:21.941 TestBackground[60867:1741136] Dismissing
>   2015-01-27 09:30:23.002 TestBackground[60867:1741136] After Runloop
>   2015-01-27 09:30:23.003 TestBackground[60867:1741136] method returning

The enqueued `dismissViewControllerAnimated` is executed *before* the method returns and the correct screenshot is taken.
This happens because I tell the current runLoop to start again from that point. The `runUntilDate` methods makes that call not return until the specified date (in my case: 2 seconds after), but has the "collateral effect" that it continues to execute the enqueued tasks. After 2 seconds, the method returns and `applicationDidEnterBackground` can return.

I used two seconds but it should work even with a smaller amount of time. But remember that the whole `applicationDidEnterBackground` method should not exceed about 5 seconds, or the app will be killed by the system.
I don't know if I will release this code in production for my apps, however I think it can be a good alternative to the guys having problem with this issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure too, this was more a challenge to find a workaround that a try to write out good, reusable and predictable code :-)

Comment: Are you currently using this solution - is this the best you have found?

Comment: I ended up using applicationWillResignActive: to cover the sensitive data in my production app. This solution seems to work but I was not sure enough to release it in a production environment